# Select records on join where value equals something, but also when it doesn't?

Tags: mysql, database, join

I am trying to select records from 2 tables, joined by a column `unique_id` in MySQL.

Table `profile` contains 1 unique entry per player.

Table `player_current_life` contains many entries per player all with `player_current_life.is_dead = 1` and possibly 1 entry of `player_current_life.is_dead = 0`.

If the player is killed and leaves the game before creating a new character, they will not have `player_current_life.is_dead = 0`. All their records will be `player_current_life.is_dead = 1`.

I want to:
`profile.total_player_kills + player_current_life.player_kills` WHERE `player_current_life.is_dead = '0'`

BUT

If `player_current_life.is_dead = 0` doesn't exist for that user in the loop, then only pull `profile.total_player_kills`.

This will loop all players in the table and display their total kills from past lives (profile.total_player_kills) but if they have a character that isn't dead (player_current_life.is_dead = 0), pull their current life kills as well.

What I have so far that is only working IF they have a character that is alive in game.

```
SELECT sum(profile.total_player_kills + player_current_life.player_kills) AS All_Player_Kills, profile.name AS Player_Name
FROM
  profile
LEFT OUTER JOIN player_current_life
ON profile.unique_id = player_current_life.unique_id AND player_current_life.is_dead = '0'
WHERE
  profile.total_play_time + player_current_life.play_time >= 10
GROUP BY
  profile.name
```

So the short of it, pull total kills from `profile` AND from `player_current_life` as a total if they have a character that's still alive, if they don't, only pull kills from `profile`.

Here is a visual table I made to better explain what I am trying to accomplish.

```
profile (only increases when the player dies)
+-------------+-----------+--------------+
| Player_Name | unique_id | player_kills |
+-------------+-----------+--------------+
| Player1     | 12345     | 25           |
+-------------+-----------+--------------+ 
| Player2     | 67890     + 12           |
+-------------+-----------+--------------+
| Player3     | 54321     + 9            |
+-------------+-----------+--------------+

player_current_life (contains kill count not sent to "profile" where is_dead = 0)
+-------------+--------------+-----------+
| unique_id   | player_kills | is_dead   |
+-------------+--------------+-----------+
| 12345       | 8            | 0         |
+-------------+--------------+-----------+
| 12345       | 15           | 1         |
+-------------+--------------+-----------+
| 12345       | 10           | 1         |
+-------------+--------------+-----------+
| 67890       + 7            | 1         |
+-------------+--------------+-----------+
| 67890       + 5            | 1         |
+-------------+--------------+-----------+
| 54321       + 2            | 1         |
+-------------+--------------+-----------+
| 54321       + 7            | 1         |
+-------------+--------------+-----------+
| 54321       + 5            | 0         |
+-------------+--------------+-----------+
```

Output should be:

Player1 Kills = 33 (25 + 8)

Player2 Kills = 12 (12 + 0)

Player3 Kills = 14 (9 + 5)

Thanks!

Comment: http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/WHERE_conditions_on_a_LEFT_JOIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not very good practice, but if `is_dead` is zero for live players and always 1 for dead players, then `(1-is_dead)` will be 1 for warm ones and 0 for the deceased.

You could then do something like

```
SELECT (profile.total_player_kills
    + SUM((1-is_dead) * player_kills)) AS All_Player_Kills,
    profile.name AS Player_Name
FROM
  profile
LEFT OUTER JOIN player_current_life
    ON profile.unique_id = player_current_life.unique_id
WHERE
    profile.total_play_time + player_current_life.play_time >= 10
GROUP BY
    profile.name
```

where dead people have their `player_kills` multiplied by 0, therefore effectively ignored.

A better way would be

```
SELECT (profile.total_player_kills
    + SUM( CASE WHEN is_dead = 0 THEN player_kills ELSE 0 END) AS ...
```

that is more robust and can be more readily adapted to `is_dead` being a boolean type.

Even better I'd go with a subselect:

```
SELECT profile.total_player_kills + this_life.total_player_kills AS ...

FROM profile
LEFT OUTER JOIN

    ( SELECT unique_id, SUM(CASE WHEN is_dead = '0' THEN player_kills ELSE 0 END)
      AS total_player_kills
    FROM player_current_life
    GROUP BY unique_id ) AS this_life

ON (profile.unique_id = this_life.unique_id)
WHERE ...
```

The version above has a [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e1d5a/1) that you may check out.

**Notice**: I believe that this code of yours may not work properly:

```
SELECT sum(profile.total_player_kills + ...
```

because the total player kills get added once for every tuple in the current life table, not once for each player.

Comment: I am unable to change the way the data is stored as this isn't my game. I am making a stats module for it and need to work with what I've been given. I am going to edit my original post with a demo table so my question might make more sense.

Comment: Don't worry, that was understood. My last query satisfies your constraints and appears to be working. I'm preparing a SQLFiddle of it.

Comment: Very cool! I have learned something new. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [if() statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) in you SELECT clause

```
SELECT sum(profile.total_player_kills + IF(player_current_life.is_dead = '0', player_current_life.player_kills, 0)) AS All_Player_Kills, profile.name AS Player_Name
FROM
  profile
LEFT OUTER JOIN player_current_life
ON profile.unique_id = player_current_life.unique_id 
WHERE
  profile.total_play_time + player_current_life.play_time >= 10
GROUP BY
  profile.name
```

Comment: When I try this method, I get a much larger number than the intended results. Its as though the results are multiplying for the number of times `is_dead=1` is found.